# DB or Code? Which and why?

Tags: php, mysql, database, orm, local

what structure do you think is better if I use ORM and why?

1.

**cars**

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(100)
type VARCHAR(100)
```

and types store in the code constants.

2.

**car_types**

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR
```

**cars**

```
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(100)
car_type_id INT
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you know what is normalization and advantages of relationships between tables. you will go for 2 one

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you use an ORM or not (if so, the database structure will often be create automatically). The second option is always preferred since it will make your queries more efficient, you will save data storage and your database will be easier to manage.

Read up on normalization:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization